# Why is the subcommand modify-id-format missing in my AWS CLI v1.9.20

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a couple of AWS amazon linux ec2 instances running,
and I'm trying to set ec2 instance id format to longer one,
which has been released few days ago.

I'm trying this:

```
aws ec2 modify-id-format --resource instance --use-long-ids
```

But following error occurs:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

aws help
aws <command> help
aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

accept-vpc-peering-connection            | allocate-address
assign-private-ip-addresses              | associate-address
associate-dhcp-options                   | associate-route-table
..... abbreviated
```

I don't even find any modify-id-format or describe-id-format in the list above,
which are found in the reference here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/index.html
(I believe the referecne is at the latest version = 1.9.20)

My `aws --version` result is:

```
aws-cli/1.9.1 Python/2.7.10 Linux/4.1.13-18.26.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.3.1
```

(I know its weird showing 1.9.1)

My  `sudo pip install awscli==1.9.20` result is :

```
Successfully installed awscli-1.9.20 botocore-1.3.20
```

(Is there some other PROPER way to upgrade awscli?)

What can I do to really upgradethe awscli and use modify-id-format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out by myself.

`/usr/local/bin/aws --version` returns:

```
aws-cli/1.9.20 Python/2.6.9 Linux/4.1.13-18.26.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.3.20
```

`aws --version` returns:

```
aws-cli/1.9.1 Python/2.7.10 Linux/4.1.13-18.26.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.3.1
```

`which aws` returns:

```
/usr/local/bin/aws
```

This is still weird, because both points the same `aws` , but I guess this is something not relevant to this question.